# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while finding longestCommonPrefix

Tags: arrays, loops, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception

I have given a task to find longestCommonPrefix

```
fun longestCommonPrefix(list: Array<String>): String {
    if(list.isNullOrEmpty()) return ""
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    for(i in 0..list.lastIndex){
        var allMatch = true
        for(j in 1..list.lastIndex){
            if(list[0].toCharArray()[i] != list[j].toCharArray()[i]){
                allMatch = false
            }
        }
        if(allMatch){
            stringBuilder.append(list[i].toCharArray()[i])
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString()
}
```

After submitting it to leetCode it said ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
Where am i doing that exception.

Or kindly improve my logic if possible

Comment: Your compiler should tell you at least in which line the Exception occurs. Have you tried debugging to step through the code and see where it goes wrong?

Comment: I am not getting exception . I have submit my solution to leetCode . their compiler said that

Comment: I don't know leetCode. Can you compare their parameters to yours and see if they are using different ones than you? It might help if you write some unit tests to cover various cases and see if that triggers an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in construction:

```
if(list[0].toCharArray()[i] != list[j].toCharArray()[i]){
    allMatch = false
}
```

You can't apply `i` variable to `CharArray` because it may have a different size. For `CharArray` another range should be applied, e.g.:

```
val chars1 = list[0].toCharArray()
val chars2 = list[j].toCharArray()
for (k in 0..chars1.lastIndex) {

    for (t in 0..chars2.lastIndex) {

        if(chars1[k] != chars2[t]){
            allMatch = false
        }
    }
}
```